# Kubernetes Ingress nginx on Minikube fails

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

minikube v1.13.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 with Kubernetes v1.19.0 on Docker 19.03.8. Using helm/helmfile ("v3.3.4"). The Ubuntu VM is on VM-Workstation running on Win10, networking set as NAT, everything in my home wifi network.

I am trying to use `ingress-backend stable/nginx-ingress 1.36.0` . I do have the `nginx-ingress-1.36.0.tgz` in the ingress/charts folder, and I have ingress/enabled `minikube addons enable ingress`.

Before I had enabled ingress on minikube, everything will get deployed successfully (no errors) but the service/LB stayed pending:

```
  ClusterIP      10.101.41.156    <none>        8080/TCP  

    ingress-controller-nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.98.157.222    <pending>     80:30050/TCP,443:32294/TCP
```

After I enabled ingress on minikube, I now get this `connection refused` error:

```
STDERR:
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch "ingress-service" with kind Ingress: 
    Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.kube-system.svc:443/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=30s": 
    dial tcp 10.105.131.220:443: connect: connection refused
        
COMBINED OUTPUT:
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch "ingress-service" with kind Ingress: 
    Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.kube-system.svc:443/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=30s":
     dial tcp 10.105.131.220:443: connect: connection refused
```

I don't know what is this IP 10.105.131.220 - *looks like pvt IP*. It is not my minikube IP, or my VM IP or my laptop IP, I cant ping it.

But it all still deploys fine- but the Load Balancer still shows `pending`.

## Update

I had missed one of the Steps based on [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#minikube)

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml`

I stopped/deleted minkube and redid everything, now the error is gone, but the loadbalancer is still `<pending>`

Answer (score 0):

By default all solutions like `minikube` does not provide you `LoadBalancer`. Cloud solutions like EKS, Google Cloud, Azure do it for you automatically by spinning in the background separate LB. Thats why you see `Pending` status.

Solutions:

1. use [MetalLB on minikube](https://medium.com/@shoaib_masood/metallb-network-loadbalancer-minikube-335d846dfdbe)

[MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/concepts/)  hooks into your Kubernetes cluster, and provides a network load-balancer implementation. In short, it allows you to create Kubernetes services of type `LoadBalancer` in clusters that don’t run on a cloud provider, and thus cannot simply hook into paid products to provide load-balancers.

Installation:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/metallb/v0.8.1/manifests/metallb.yaml

namespace/metallb-system created
podsecuritypolicy.policy/speaker created
serviceaccount/controller created
serviceaccount/speaker created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metallb-system:controller created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metallb-system:speaker created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/config-watcher created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metallb-system:controller created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metallb-system:speaker created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/config-watcher created
```

2. use [minikube tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel)

> Services of type LoadBalancer can be exposed via the minikube tunnel
> command. It must be run in a separate terminal window to keep the
> LoadBalancer running. Ctrl-C in the terminal can be used to terminate
> the process at which time the network routes will be cleaned up.

`minikube tunnel` runs as a process, creating a network route on the host to the service CIDR of the cluster using the cluster’s IP
address as a gateway. The tunnel command exposes the external IP
directly to any program running on the host operating system.

Comment: Thanks, Ok I will try MetalLB. And yes, my original understanding was you need a cloud provider to get a load balancer - but some documentation indicated I could do it with nginx/ingress. So what good is this - how/what for do I use this nginx/ingress?

Comment: i believe you better create second post and ask there purpose of nginx/ingress usage. Huge topic and you will have lots opinion and explanations there.  This question is about `Pending` state in non-cloud solutions

Comment: Tried implementing metallb, had to retrofit my helmfile. Had to use bitnami/stable. After all that: `MetalLB is now running in the cluster` . `ingress-backend      bitnami/metallb    0.1.24`.   `LoadBalancer Services in your cluster are now available on the IPs you defined in MetalLB's configuration`.  `ingress-backend default  metallb-0.1.24  0.9.3`. But I dont see any loadbalancer created- `kubectl get services -o wide --all-namespaces ` - I get everything else but no loadbalancer created.
So will have to debug/research.

Comment: Tried the hello world as in the link, **did not work** - the loadbalncer shows <pending>  `nginx        LoadBalancer   10.111.44.136    <pending>     80:31009/TCP   10m`

Comment: configured [configmap](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/)?

Comment: followed [official guides](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/) ?

Comment: Yes I followed all steps, configmap, set IP address range as suggested- my minikube IP 172.17.0.3 -> `172.17.0.0-172.17.0.10`

Comment: Actually now I noticed I had not `strictARP: true` I did that, restarted minikube and re-deployed service but still <pending>